# How to use \printglossary in a footnote?

Tags: footnotes, glossaries

I would like to have my glossaries printed inside a footnote.
But I get a huge gap between the footnote and the actual printing of the glossaries.

That is the code in a minimalistic way:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[
    nopostdot,
        acronym,
    nonumberlist,
    nomain,
    sort=def,
    nostyles,
    translate=babel,
 ]{glossaries}

\setglossarypreamble[acronym]{Nomenklatur und Auflösung der Typologie der Löcher.}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\setglossarystyle{mcolindex}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{typ:e}{
    type=\acronymtype, 
    name={E}, 
    description={Einfassung}, 
    first={Einfassung (E)}, 
}
\newglossaryentry{typ:eh}{
    type=\acronymtype, 
    name={Eh}, 
    description={Einfassung, horizontal.}, 
    first={Einfassung, horizontal (Eh)}, 
    parent={typ:e}
}
\begin{document}
\gls{typ:eh}\\
\gls{typ:e}\\
\gls{typ:eh}\\
\gls{typ:e}\\
\footnote{\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,%
    title = {}]}
\end{document}
```

And that is the result:

[image: glossaries in footnote]

Comment: I really don't see a point in doing so, you will have one list of acronyms per page then? Why not adding the footnotes manually??

Comment: Setting the title to empty doesn't remove the chapter header. It simply does an empty chapter header. You'll need to do something like `\renewcommand\glossarysection[2][]{}`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot This works very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Converting my comment into an answer). You need to completely remove the chapter heading, rather than simply set the title to empty. The glossary chapter/section heading is set with `\glossarysection[toc title]{title}`, so this command can simply be redefined to do nothing:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[
    nopostdot,
        acronym,
    nonumberlist,
    nomain,
    sort=def,
    nostyles,
    translate=babel,
 ]{glossaries}

\setglossarypreamble[acronym]{Nomenklatur und Auflösung der
Typologie der Löcher.}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\setglossarystyle{mcolindex}

\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{typ:e}{
    type=\acronymtype, 
    name={E}, 
    description={Einfassung}, 
    first={Einfassung (E)}, 
}
\newglossaryentry{typ:eh}{
    type=\acronymtype, 
    name={Eh}, 
    description={Einfassung, horizontal.}, 
    first={Einfassung, horizontal (Eh)}, 
    parent={typ:e}
}

\begin{document}
\gls{typ:eh}\\
\gls{typ:e}\\
\gls{typ:eh}\\
\gls{typ:e}\\
\footnote{\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of footnote]